# 3D моделирование на плоскости

Tags: c++, qt, 3d

Добрый день всем! Стоит задача моделирования 3D-объекта (например, куба) на плоскости. OpenGL пользоваться нельзя. Нужно всё сделать ручками. 3D-примитив должен задаваться списком граней.

Непонятно следующее: есть двумерная плоскость (Canvas какой-нибудь), на ней надо нарисовать 3D-объект. Как трактовать координату Z? Как её правильно задавать?

Использую Qt, может в Qt есть трёхмерная система координат? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Qt какбы и 3d рендер есть, но он использует OpenGL, который вам не нравится.

Вот [один из мануалов](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248153/).

Более простое описание - учебник Немнюгина по Паскалю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы преобразовывать координаты, нужно составить матрицы специального вида - матрицы трансформаций и матрицы проектирования, а затем умножать координаты 3d точек на эти матрицы и получать 2d точки.

Comment: а причём тут учебник по паскалю ? ))

Comment: @ampawd при том, что там хороший теоретический раздел, не привязанный к языку.

Comment: так лучше б книгу по основам комп графики порекомендовали бы

Comment: @ampawd Кнопка "Добавить ответ" где-то тут рядом - дерзайте.